# Steps for vector equation of the tangent line

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I am asked to find the vector equation of the tangent line at the indicated point.

[image: this]

I have the answers to check my work, they are [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5AA7.png)

I want to know why the asnwer for $1$ is with $k$, and answer $3$ is just vector notation? Am I supposed to do something different for 1 vs 3?

Comment: $k$ is a coordinate describing position along the tangent line. For 3, the tangent line is really just a point (the derivative is $0$), so no $k$ is needed.

Comment: While solving for the equation, will I find out when $k$ is just a point and when it isn't? In  other words, how would I know when it is or isn't just a point?

Comment: For 3 the equation of the tangent line is $(x,y)=(0,0)+k(0,0)$ which doesn't depend on $k$. In general the equation is $(x,y)=\mathbf r(t_0)+k\mathbf r'(t_0)$ so you only need to consider whether $\mathbf r'(t_0)=0$.

Comment: What if $r(t) = (x,y,z)$? A vector in 3D?

Comment: Same expression, $\mathbf r(t_0)+k\mathbf r'(t_0)$, which is a proper line if and only if $\mathbf r'(t_0)\neq0$.

Comment: Alright, thank  you!